# Best way for dynamic interface, loaded from database, in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to rewrite a webapp, and I would like to do it in React.

How it currently works is that in the database there's a row for each "page", which could be something like

```
{
  row: 1,
  column: 2,
  width: 2,
  height: 1,
  data: 'Why hello there',
  componentType: 'Box'
}
```

So, I have two problems here:

**One:** I would like to dynamically load a React component ("Box") that I did not know about at run-time.

**Two:** Is there some obvious way of doing the component/layout switching here? I know about react-routes, but all the tutorials I have seen shows it to be a lot more "static" (where you basically already know all your views and routes before the app starts, and where it doesn't really seem possible to get that data from a database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to render a version of your app that is essentially "blank". Whether it be through a splash screen or loading spinners, or some combination of the two, or something else.

Then after the app mounts, in your `componentDidMount` method, you do an http request to an API running on a server that fetches data from a database and returns your data in a format your webapp understands (probably JSON). Then you populate your app with the returned data, turning off any loading screens or spinners when it's done.

Check out [this example from the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html).

Comment: Hi Danny - thanks for the reply. I know how to use ajax to set the state. I am unsure how to dynamically add new components to other components, while trying to mimic a borderlayout. - Basically mounting and unmounting components manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webpack dynamic bundle loading